# Syntax error with unioned tables

Tags: php, mysql

This query works...

```
$stm = $pdo->prepare("SELECT T1.Taxon, T1.Rank, T2.Taxon, T2.Rank FROM     gz_life_reptiles_new T1
LEFT JOIN gz_life_reptiles_new T2 ON T2.Taxon = T1.Taxon
UNION
SELECT T1.Taxon, T1.Rank, T2.Taxon, T2.Rank FROM gz_life_reptiles_new T1
RIGHT JOIN gz_life_reptiles T2 ON T2.Taxon = T1.Taxon");
 $stm->execute(array(
));
```

However, I want to combine them into a single virtual table with the name "combined" so I can perform more operations, including GROUP BY, something like this...

```
$stm = $pdo->prepare("SELECT *
FROM (SELECT T1.Taxon, T1.Rank, T2.Taxon, T2.Rank FROM  gz_life_reptiles_new T1
LEFT JOIN gz_life_reptiles_new T2 ON T2.Taxon = T1.Taxon
UNION
SELECT T3.Taxon, T3.Rank, T4.Taxon, T4.Rank FROM gz_life_reptiles_new T3
RIGHT JOIN gz_life_reptiles T4 ON T4.Taxon = T3.Taxon
) AS Combined
GROUP BY Taxon");
 $stm->execute(array(
));
```

However, I didn't write it correctly. I get the error message **#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') AS Combined
GROUP BY Taxon
LIMIT 0, 30' at line 6**

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL doesn't allow subqueries in the `from` clause for a view.  So, just do:

```
SELECT T1.Taxon, T1.Rank, T2.Taxon, T2.Rank
FROM  gz_life_reptiles_new T1 LEFT JOIN
      gz_life_reptiles_new T2
      ON T2.Taxon = T1.Taxon
UNION
SELECT T3.Taxon, T3.Rank, T4.Taxon, T4.Rank
FROM gz_life_reptiles_new T3 RIGHT JOIN
     gz_life_reptiles T4
     ON T4.Taxon = T3.Taxon;
```

The `distinct` probably does what you want for removing duplicates.  If not, then you have a challenge.

EDIT:

Okay, here is another method:

```
SELECT T1.Taxon, T1.Rank, T2.Taxon, T2.Rank
FROM  gz_life_reptiles_new T1 LEFT JOIN
      gz_life_reptiles_new T2
      ON T2.Taxon = T1.Taxon
UNION ALL
SELECT T3.Taxon, T3.Rank, T4.Taxon, T4.Rank
FROM gz_life_reptiles_new T3 RIGHT JOIN
     gz_life_reptiles T4
     ON T4.Taxon = T3.Taxon
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM gz_life_reptiles_new T1
                  WHERE T4.Taxon = T1.Taxon
                 );
```

By the way, do you intend for the first `LEFT JOIN` to be on `gz_life_reptiles_new` twice?  The structure of your query is usually to approximate a FULL OUTER JOIN and the structure is: "FROM A LEFT JOIN B UNION ALL FROM B LEFT JOIN A".  That is, the same tables are in both queries.

Comment: Sorry, how/where do you implement DISTINCT?

Comment: @DavidBlomstrom . . . The `union` removes duplicates.  But, it is removing duplicates on all the columns, not just the first.

Comment: Actually, it's displaying duplicates. For example, if Table 1 features 'A' and Table 2 features 'A' and 'B', then it displays 'A' and later displays 'A' and 'B'. It looks like it's essentially displaying all of the first table, followed by all of the second table.

Comment: Your second query nailed it. I've been trying to do the MySQL equivalent of a full outer join in order to compare two tables, and your query does the job.